# Order in included model

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to use "order" on an included model in sequelize

Here's the code :

```
let category = await Category.findOne({
    where: {
      slug: req.params.slug,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: Category,
        as: "subcategories",
      },
      {
        model: Product,
        as: "products",
        include: [
          {
            model: File,
            as: "files",
          },
          {
            model: Product,
            as: "variations",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    order: [{ model: Product, as: "variations" }, "price", "DESC"]
  });
```

This code returns : Unable to find a valid association for model, 'Product'.
I have tried many solutions but don't find one working, and don't find much documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You indicated `Product` with an alias from an association with `File` model and not with `Category` and you obviously don't have such association between `Category` and `Product`. You need to indicate the whole chain to get to `variations` association in `order` option.

```js
order: [[Sequelize.col('products.variations.price'), "DESC"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this(including for many sub-ordering):

```js
Category.findOne({
    where: {...},
    include: [...],
    order: [
        [Product, "price", "DESC"]
    ],
});
```